# Text in div style issue float doesn't work as i want

Tags: html, css

.Hi. This might be a common/easy question but i couldn't figured it out for hours. I've been creating a user form to print, but as you can see(in snipped), the text doesn't go right with float. Can someone help me about it?
Thanks in advance.

```css
.formInf 
{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:15px;
    font-size:13px;
    float:right; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    margin-top:2px;
}

.line 
{
    margin-top:5px;
    width:98%;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>27/05/2017</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>Ataoglu</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>areaareaarearaearasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</b></p></div>
```

Comment: the problem is the margin bottom of `p` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple floating problem. Add this:

```
.line {
  clear:both;    /* add this line */
```

When possible you can avoid using `float` and do it instead using `text-align`

```css
.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: right;       /* 1. */
}

.formInf {
  display: inline-block;   /* 2. */
  vertical-align: top;     /* 3. */
  margin:0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <p class="formInf"><b>27/05/2017</b></p>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <p class="formInf"><b>Ataoglu</b></p>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <p class="formInf"><b>areaareaarearaearasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</b></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks. It looks really easy but somehow, i couldn't find the solution. Now i have the solution thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1:

**Apply `float:left;` or `display:inline-block` or `clear:both` to .line (the parent div).**

> Here you go :

```css
.formInf 
{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:15px;
    font-size:13px;
    float:right; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    margin-top:2px;
}

.line 
{
    margin-top:5px;
    width:98%;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>27/05/2017</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>Ataoglu</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>areaareaarearaearasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</b></p></div>
```

Solution 2: 
**Change the margin of `p tags`.**

> Here you go :

```css
.formInf 
{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:15px;
    font-size:13px;
    float:right; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    margin-top:2px;
}

.line 
{
    margin-top:5px;
    width:98%;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    
    
}
.line  p{ margin:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>27/05/2017</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>Ataoglu</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>areaareaarearaearasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</b></p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Comment: You are always welcome :) i also used to get stuck on small things sometimes when I was newbie :)

Comment: @FurkanAyık I dont know why he downvoted :( Because my answer is correct and also gives a lot of options too

Answer (score 0):

Override the default margin.

```css
.formInf {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  float: right;
  margin: 2px 10px 0px 0px;

  
}

.line {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 98%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <p class="formInf"><b>27/05/2017</b></p>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <p class="formInf"><b>Ataoglu</b></p>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <p class="formInf"><b>areaareaarearaearasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</b></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>.formInf 
{
    clear:right;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:15px;
    font-size:13px;
    float:right; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    margin-top:2px;
}

.line 
{
    margin-top:5px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>27/05/2017</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>Ataoglu</b></p></div>
        <div class="line"><p class="formInf"><b>areaareaarearaearasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</b></p></div>
```

The "clear: right" act as break line, i also remove the line:-width:98% is obstructing the other div

Answer (score -1):

Because each div has class line  and you mention in css that .line should have width 98%. Change the width or remove class = line from children div.

Answer (score -1):

In `.formInf` class just replace `float:right;`  with `text-align:right;`

Comment: Thanks for downvote , anyway It works and it is the simpliest fix for your code. Have a nice day